# create posts with read only tags in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, tags, associations

I have 2 models lets say Group & User. A Group can have many Users & a User can have many Groups.

How to make sure, when posting on a particular group, they can only use the tags that have been created by the admin & not all the tags present in all the Groups?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the admin is creating the group, he can assign the list of tags available only to this one.

```
class User < AR::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :groups
end

class Group < AR::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users
  has_many :tags
end

class Tag < AR::Base
  belongs_to :group
end
```

Then the user can get the list of available tags:

```
user.groups.first.tags #=> the list of available tags
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Give the user a [dropdown](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-select_tag) to choose tags only created by the admin
2. Validate the tags with a custom [validation method](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#custom-methods)